# What was the "revolutionary" digital camera with infinite depth of field and focus adjustment in post-processing?

Tags: history, camera, light-field, lytro

A few years ago (at least 10 years I believe), I read in a magazine about a "revolutionary" camera which was able to take pictures such that from **one** picture you could, **afterwards**, choose the point you wanted to focus on (during the post-processing).

I do not remember the name of that camera, I just recall it was in the shape of a cuboid (a rather long one) and (very vague memory) that it was black or red.

I could not find anything online but would be interested to see what it has become (and read about the technology - if it was not snake oil).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing you're referring to the [Lytro by Lytro, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lytro) It's an example of a [light-field or plenoptic camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-field_camera).

Comment: And to add -- it wasn't snake oil, in that it did what it said it did (allowed for refocusing in postprocessing). The tech behind it is actually really cool. It was, however, not commercially successful.